# Scanner object doesn't read user input; java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

I don't know why when I run this part of the code, it doesn't let me type in anything.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IRA {

    public void select() {
        
        Scanner options = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("What do you want to do: \na) Add cash \nb) Invest \nc) Transfer money \nd) Exchange currencies");
        
        System.out.println("Please, enter a, b, c or d: ");

        String letter = options.nextLine();
        
        char c = letter.charAt(0);
```

Comment: Did you try to use `public static void main(String[] args) ` instead of `public void select()`?

Comment: In some part of your program/application, you are closing the `Scanner` for `System.in`. Note that this action closes the `System.in` as well and there is no way to open it again without restarting the JVM.

Comment: Thanks Live and Let Live !